# How to implement Interface method with subclass argument?

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

This is the interface

```
public interface ITransporter
{
    TransporterType TransporterType { get; set; }
    TransportActionResults BeginTransport(
        Project sourceProject, 
        ProjectBase targetProject);

    bool CheckTargetExists(ProjectBase project);
}
```

Here `ProjectBase` is an abstract class for all types of project classes.
Here is the method inside the class that implements `ITransporter` interface.

```
public class LocalTransporter : ITransporter
{
    public TransportActionResults BeginTransport(
        Project sourceProject, 
        TargetLocalProject targetProject)
    {
        return TransportActionResults.Success;
    }
```

This `TargetLocalProject` class inherits from `ProjectBase` class. However, I get an error that says "LocalTransporter class does not implement interface member" and points to the `BeginTransport` method.

Here is my problem. I need to implement the interface's `BeginTransport` method using base class `ProjectBase` because there are couple of different project classes inherited from the base class and we don't know which one will be used.

Moreover, there are couple of differen `Transporter` types so that I need to interact with it using an interface `ITransporter`.

**Note:** I considered implementing the method using `ProjectBase` instead of `TargetLocalProject` but when using `LocalTransporter` directly (instead of thruogh interface) the argument's type should be the specific Project type instead of base class.

I hope I made myself clear. So, is there a way to implement this interface method using base class in interface but subclass in implemented method?

Comment: Sounds like you want to make your interface generic.

Comment: @juharr You are right, as well as the answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use generics for this, just change your interface a little bit:

```
public interface ITransporter<T> where T : ProjectBase
{
    TransporterType TransporterType { get; set; }
    TransportActionResults BeginTransport(Project sourceProject, T targetProject);

    bool CheckTargetExists(T project);
}
```

Then you can implement it in your concrete class:

```
public class LocalTransporter : ITransporter<TargetLocalProject>
{
    public TransportActionResults BeginTransport(Project sourceProject, TargetLocalProject targetProject)
    {
        return TransportActionResults.Success;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried and this solved the problem perfectly. Thank you very much. Accepting the answer in 6 minutes=)

Answer (score 1):

You could provide an explicit interface implementation as follows:

```
internal class LocalTransporter : ITransporter
{
    public TransportActionResults BeginTransport(
        Project sourceProject,
        TargetLocalProject targetProject)
    {
        // specific implementation
        return TransportActionResults.Success;
    }

    public TransporterType TransporterType { get; set; }

    TransportActionResults ITransporter.BeginTransport(Project sourceProject, ProjectBase targetProject)
    {
        // generic implementation
        return TransportActionResults.Success;
    }

    public bool CheckTargetExists(ProjectBase project)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

You may want to consider using the [visitor pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/visitor) here.